# Merging [case-sensitive] and [case-insensitive] tags

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

I found that there are two tags [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-sensitive) and [case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-insensitive)

I believe that questions regarding case sensitive and insensitive topics all fall under the same [case-sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-sensitivity) topic. If I ask a question about [case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-insensitive) regex comparison, I'm implicitly talking about a system that currently compares regex [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-sensitive) and which I want to transform.

I mean that the two are the opposite faces of the same coin.

For me, they should be merged.

Example questions for [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-sensitive)

- [How can I make SQL case sensitive string comparison on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629111/how-can-i-make-sql-case-sensitive-string-comparison-on-mysql)
- [git mv and only change case of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011625/git-mv-and-only-change-case-of-directory)
- [indexOf Case Sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126227/indexof-case-sensitive)

Example questions for [case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-insensitive):

- [Case-insensitive search in Rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220423/case-insensitive-search-in-rails-model)
- [How to replace case-insensitive literal substrings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054995/how-to-replace-case-insensitive-literal-substrings-in-java)
- [Why are functions and methods in PHP case-insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749781/why-are-functions-and-methods-in-php-case-insensitive)

Example for both:

- [How do I make jQuery Contains case insensitive, including jQuery 1.8+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196641/how-do-i-make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive-including-jquery-1-8)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that [tag:case-sensitivity] is already a synonym of [tag:case-sensitive].  So you are basically asking to reverse the synonyms and then make [tag:case-insensitive] a synonym  of it too.

Comment: Well, I didn't see the case-sensitivity tag (maybe because auto-completor hides synonims). Now that I think about it, yes, I'm actually asking to reverse synonims and make case-insensitive a synonim of case-sensitivity. My idea is that case-sensitivity should group question for both cases.

Comment: You wouldn't have seen it in the autocompletion because it is a synonym. You only see the "parent" tag even when typing the synonym (but if you look at the ***see also:*** at the bottom of the wiki excerpt, when you are in the tag window, you will see case-insensitivity.  But I only noticed it when I was trying to add the proper tag markup to your question and click the case-sensitivity tag and saw I was browsing case-sensitive questions.

Comment: Tags are a feature of the site, but specific tags and synonyms thereof aren't tags, so I changed your [feature-request] to [support]. You can add [discussion] if you want, but I think it is pretty clear and nothing to discuss.

Comment: I'm suggesting a broader clean up of related tags: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307151/up-with-capitalization