# Burninate [case-sensitive]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/case-sensitive) tag (x915) seems very broad and unnecessary. It currently has 4 (yes, four) followers.

Criteria from the rules:

- *Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?*

  - Not in any meaningful way. It just signifies that case-sensitivity is *somehow* involved.
- *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?*

  - Maybe?
- *Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?*

  - Not really.
- *Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?*

  - Not even close. It is used in a wide variety of contexts for all kinds of issues and languages.

No one can be an expert at case-sensitivity. I can't imagine anyone seeking out such questions. It is simply not useful.

Comment: Strongly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281064/215552

Comment: Note that there are other tags regarding case, like `lowercase`, `uppercase`, `ignore-case`, `title-case`, `pascal-case`, `sentencecase`, and likely more...